# Increase div height to fit ajax accordion

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax

I have the following layout on a webpage

```
    <asp:panel id="overview_pnl">
      <asp:panel id="top_row" CssClass="overviewRows">
        <ajaxToolKit:Accordion>
           <Panes>
              <AccordionPane id="pane1">

                  <header> ... </header>
                  <content> <div id="detail" class="details"> </div> </content>          

              </AccordionPane>
          </Panes>
        </ajaxToolKit:Accordion>
      </asp:panel >
      <asp:panel id="middle_row">
         ... same as top row ...
      </asp:panel >

      <asp:panel id="bottom_row">

      </asp:panel >

  </asp:panel >
```

Css

```
.overviewRows { width:508px; vertical-align:top; display:inline-block; float:left;  }
.details {
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    width: 154px;
    border: 1px #CCC solid;
    border-top: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I want the div with the id "top_row" to have its height expanded to fit the entire pane and push down the middle and bottom divs so the content doesn't overflow into them.

I have tried `overflow` in the css but it didn't work quite the way I wanted. It brought on scroll bars for the height before the accordian was expanded and I had to scroll to see the data. I just want it to push everything down and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Show us the CSS for it?

Comment: Can you add a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Set the height for top_row to 100%?

Comment: The 100% height doesn't work @IrishChieftain, I've tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know the intended height you want your accordion to be then? You can add a min-height property to make sure it meets that requirement?

Comment: I know the height it has to be but if I make that the minimum height it defeats the purpose of the question.

Comment: Not exactly, but if you can post something to jsfiddle for people to play around with it will help a bunch, thanks.